# How to add extra style to an existing text macro?

Tags: macros, expl3

I'm trying to create a command `\mymodule_add_text_style:nn` for adding extra style to an existing text macro. As you can see from the following MWE, it can successfully add the style `\textsc` to `\mytext`. However, the command doesn't work if one wish to add another style to the same macro. Why does it fail and how can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\mytext{My text}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_add_text_style:nn
  {
    \tl_gset:cx { #1 } { \exp_not:n { #2 } { \use:c { #1 } } }
  }

\mymodule_add_text_style:nn
  { mytext }
  { \textsc }
% \mymodule_add_text_style:nn
%   { mytext }
%   { \textcolor {red} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mytext{} and more text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `x`-expand something that might not survive it, in this case `\textsc` (but also `\textcolor` if you want to add something again). In order to achieve your goal, you need to better control the expansions, doing *exactly* one expansion of `\mytext` when redefining it.

However, your call should be like

```
\mymodule_add_text_style:cn
  { mytext }
  { \textsc }
```

because you're using `mytext` as a csname. Here the function is a variant of `\mymodule_add_text_style:Nn`, so you'll also be able to call

```
\mymodule_add_text_style:Nn \mytext { \textsc }
```

There's no need to use `\exp_not:n` or variants thereof: just use variants. Doing no `x`-expansion is much safer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\mytext{My text}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_add_text_style:Nn
  {
    \__mymodule_add_text_style:Non #1 { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mymodule_add_text_style:Nn { c }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mymodule_add_text_style:Nnn
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn #1 { #3 { #2 } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mymodule_add_text_style:Nnn { No }

\mymodule_add_text_style:cn
  { mytext }
  { \textsc }
\mymodule_add_text_style:cn
  { mytext }
  { \textcolor {red} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\show\mytext

\mytext{} and more text.

\end{document}
```

The console will present

```
> \mytext=macro:
->\textcolor {red}{\textsc {My text}}.
```

as desired.

[image]

Can you see the trick? You pass `#1` twice, but to a variant of an auxiliary function where the second argument is expanded once.

Note also that *any* function that performs assignments should be `protected`.

###### Slightly different proposal

Since you're using `\mytext` as a token list variable (this is a bit of stretch, but not so much), using `V` type would be good:

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_add_text_style:Nn
  {
    \__mymodule_add_text_style:NVn #1 #1 { #2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mymodule_add_text_style:Nn { c }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mymodule_add_text_style:Nnn
  {
    \tl_gset:Nn #1 { #3 { #2 } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mymodule_add_text_style:Nnn { NV }
```

Comment: I'd wondered about using that form, duplicating the argument, it avoids `\exp_not:..` but is a bit more complicated I think, but anyway the tick got well placed:-) (+1 consolation prize)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To the contrary, it's more natural in `expl3` style. The argument is used twice, in different ways, so pass it twice and let variants take care of expansions.

Comment: oh no, disaster!

Answer (score 3):

You can create the macro `\addstyle \macro {style}` using TeX primitives without any expl3. It does the same work:

```
\def\addstyle#1{\expandafter\addstyleA\expandafter{#1}#1}
\def\addstyleA#1#2#3{\def#2{#3{#1}}}

\def\mytext{My text}

\addstyle \mytext {\textsc}
\addstyle \mytext {\textcolor{red}}

\meaning\mytext  % macro:->\textcolor {red}{\textsc {My text}}

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first use you have

```
\textsc {My text}
```

`\textsc` is protected using LaTeX `\protect` mechanism but can't be used in `\edef` or other expansion contexts such as an `x` argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\mytext{My text}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_add_text_style:Nn
  {
    \tl_set:Nx #1  { \exp_not:n { #2}{\exp_not:o { #1 }}}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\mymodule_add_text_style:Nn {c}

\mymodule_add_text_style:cn
  { mytext }
  { \textsc }

\show\mytext

\mymodule_add_text_style:cn
  { mytext }
  { \textcolor {red} }

\show\mytext

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mytext{} and more text.

\end{document}
```

the two `\show` show

```
> \mytext=macro:
->\textsc {My text}.
l.20 \show\mytext
                 
? 
> \mytext=macro:
->\textcolor {red}{\textsc {My text}}.
l.26 \show\mytext
                 
?
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you please explain in a little more detail why `\exp_args:No \exp_not:n { #1 }` works? I don't quite understand the combination here.

Comment: you need to expand `\mytext` once (only) to get `\etxtsc{mytext}`  so `\exp_args:No ` expands it once (the `o`) and then `\exp_not:n` stops it expanding any more (inside the expansion context set up by `\tl_set:Nx`  (note I removed the `g` as there doesn't appear to be any requiremnt fro global definitions here @Jinwen

Comment: There's also `\exp_not:o` instead of the clumsy `\exp_args:No \exp_not:n { #1 }`

Comment: @egreg ah yes I'll update